# Is Membership payment on Drupal 8 Webform supported yet?

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, drupal-8

I am trying to configure a Drupal 8 Webform to support payment for Memberships, but there seems no connection between the Membership field and the Payment fields.  On D7, when configuring a Contribution on a Webform it asks for a Contribution Page to use, but not on D8.

Is this a bug, or just not yet implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a new feature! It is no longer necessary to create a Contribution Page

Comment: Karin - got a link to a documentation page?

Comment: No - not yet! It’s pretty straightforward though! :-)

Comment: OK, thanks.  I have just rebuilt my webform (and had updated the code as well), and it is now creating a membership and a payment.  There are a few further comments I will raise separately.